# Terraform won't stop destroying resource groups after a TF Apply

Tags: azure, terraform

I have vnet module and subnet module that I am using as layers and i am creating subnets through locals for the subnet prefixes and names. I am also using a data block to reference the outputs for the vnet resourcegroup and region, but when i do a tf apply its destroying the resource groups , is there a way to prevent this? i have also added lifecycle prevent destroy at the root module resource group.

Here is my code:

```
data "azurerm_subscription" "current" {} 
data "terraform_remote_state" "resource-group"  {
  backend = "azurerm"
  config = {
    resource_group_name = cremote-state-config.resource_group_name
    storage_account_name = local.data.remote-state-config.storage_account_name
    container_name = local.data.remote-state-config.container_name
    key = "resource-groups.tfstate"
  }
} 

module "vnet" {
  source = "../modules/vnet"
  count = local.data.inflate ? 1 : 0
  vnet-name = local.data..vnet-name

  resource-group-name = data.terraform_remote_state.resource-group.outputs.hub.name
  region = data.terraform_remote_state.resource-group.outputs.hub.location
  vnet-address-space = local.data.address_prefix tags = local.data.tags
} 

module "subnet" {
  source = "../modules/subnet"
  for_each = local.subnets
  subnet-name = each.value.subnet_name
  resource-group-name = data.terraform_remote_state.resource-group.outputs.hub.name
  vnet-name = module.vnet[0].vnet.name
  subnet-prefixes = each.value.address_prefixes
}
```

destroy message am getting:

```
module.spoke-resourcegroup.azurerm_resource_group.rg will be destroyed

module.hub-resourcegroup.azurerm_resource_group.rg will be destroyed

(because azurerm_resource_group.rg is not in configuration)
```

I have a backend file which creates 1 state file for resource group e.g. rg.tfstate and another backend.tf inside the vnet folder to create networking.tfstate I also added lifecycle prevent destroy still it keeps destroying the resource groups..

Pls help

Tried using lifecycle prevent destroy still won't stop from destroying resource groups.

Answer (score 0):

Before running your terraform code goo to the working directory and check state file.

```
cd $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)
terraform state list
terraform state rm $(terraform state list)
```

This should clear your resources set for deletion on next run. Run `terraform state list` again if this shows 0 resources, you are good to deploy your terraform code without deleting previous resources.